# MegaRAID Rebuild required after PdOffline + PdOnline?

Tags: raid, storage, lsi, megaraid

In a RAID6 array with 12 disks I have taken a disk offline to flash new firmware, then brought it online again:

```
MegaCli64 -PdOffline -PhysDrv[8:0] -a0
MegaCli64 -PdFwDownload -PhysDrv[8:0] -f firmware/ConstellationES3-Megalodon-SATA-StdOEM-SN06.lod -a0
MegaCli64 -PdOnline -PhysDrv[8:0] -a0
```

I then checked the status of the controller with `MegaCli64 -AdpEventLog -GetLatest 100`. Surprisingly the virtual drive changed its state from "partially degraded" to "optimal" immediately. Can I really trust this information? I had expected that a rebuild is required, because the drive was offline for a few minutes and it did not get any writes during this time. Should I force a rebuild for this drive, just to be sure?

I want to make sure that my virtual drive is in good shape before I take the next drive offline for the firmware upgrade.

Controller is a LSI MegaRAID SAS 9271-8i, FW Package Build: 23.29.0-0016.

Please advise.